# Can Python Script be included in PHP?

Tags: php, python-2.7

I want to implement one logic which is written in python, this code will do some searching stuffs, and I have a website done in PHP. can any one tell me whether I can include python script in PHP? if yes , how can I do that ?

> Criteria : 
>   Input to the python script will come from php or html [either text or file]. and output of python is directly displayed to the page or through php or store it in mysql and show it through PHP.[Please suggest me the best one in this].

Comment: out of curiosity, why cant you do the "searching stuff" with php?

Comment: requirement , the code is already written in python and i heard that its alot faster then PHP.

Comment: "alot faster than PHP" on its own, in very specific situations, yes. However, PHP is already running in your situation - might as well use it?

Comment: see whats happening in python code is :
entered Input may be some text or a word file is searched in google. and the result will be multiple site url and content which has matched with the user contents.
i really dono how we can do this in php and i dont think it will be faster in php.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to `exec`, you can run the python interpreter. However, that's:

1. Overkill
2. Not necessarily wise
3. A major waste of resources

If your logic is simple, why don't you write it in PHP? Furthermore, if your logic is **not** simple...why don't you make an API of some sort to access it and favour communication rather than code deduplication?

Comment: how can i make an API and use it ?

Comment: Write your python code as an executable that either feeds back through HTTP or through standard I/O the result, then parse that using PHP.

Comment: Please give me more details on your last comment.

Comment: can you please provide more details